# Cache breaker as query parameter vs cache breaker in filename

Tags: css, browser-cache

We have come across 2 ways to do cache breaking for our CSS files.

Cache breaker passed as a query parameter:

```
http://your1337site.com/styles/cool.css?v=123
```

Cache breaker as part of the name:

```
http://your1337site.com/styles/123.cool.css
```

Which way is better?  And why?

I feel that the second way is more verbose, because the file matches the name on the folder structure.  Where as the first way is good if you want to share "cool.css" on other parts of the site, which don't have access to the unique name you generate each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steve Souder's article [Revving Filenames: don’t use querystring](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/) makes a good argument for changing the filename as the better of the two.

> ...a co-worker, Jacob Hoffman-Andrews, mentioned that Squid, a popular proxy, doesn’t cache resources with a querystring. This hurts performance when multiple users behind a proxy cache request the same file – rather than using the cached version everybody would have to send a request to the origin server.

As an aside, Squid 2.7 and above does [cache dynamic content with the default configuration](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent)